# Rails, Facebook API, Koala gem — get all profiles of users who 'Like' a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

Using Rails3 and koala gem, how to retrive all profiles of users who 'Like' a FB page (http://facebook.com/DAKINE for example). Is it possible at all?
As the final result i need to get a bunch of user profiles, stored in db.

Thanks!

Comment: That would probably be illegal...

Comment: Umm.. Why? As an admin of FB Page, i can see all users who like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy to get the likes of any page on facebook, particularly with the Koala gem. Since the facebook likes for a given page are publically accessible ([see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)), you can access them without using an API key.

For example, to obtain the number of likes for this page: [facebook.com/foofighters](http://www.facebook.com/foofighters) you could do:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new
likes = graph.get_object("foofighters")["likes"]
```

I'm assuming you have your user profiles stored in your application database, and each (or some) of these have associated facebook IDs? If you're trying to save the 'like' data locally for your users, you could do something along the lines of:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new
@users.each do |user|
  user.likes = graph.get_object(user.facebook_id)["likes"]
  user.save
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually i need to get info from each profile (like link to profile, userpic or any public available info) of user who press 'Like' on specific page (for example 'foofighters'). Is it possible?

Comment: As of facebook api version 2.1, `graph.get_object("foofighters")["likes"]` just returns the likes count, not the individual likers.

Comment: @s2t2 How can we get the individual likers ?

Comment: Looked at the API 2.2 and it looks like there is no way, kinda disappointing.

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen Whilst I haven't tried it, [version 2.2 of the API docs for object/likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes/) states as the return value: "An array of User objects representing each of the people who liked the object, in addition to the following field: `total_count` Total number of people who liked. This is only returned when the flag `summary=true` is set."