# How To Get A List Of Facebook Users That Have Liked Our Page Using Koala Gem For Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I want to get a list of all the Facebook users who have liked our Facebook page using the Koala gem for Ruby on Rails.

Ideally returned as a JSON hash with the user objects so can get access to their feeds, and using just the page access token as we currently do not offer Facebook login.

The docs say acting as a page is much the same as acting as a user and the same commands should work. Which means this should work -

`@page_graph.get_connections("me", "friends")`

But this returns -

`Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (friends) on node type (Page), x-fb-trace-id: EzD1J26UONf [HTTP 400]`

The only other Stack post I can find on this is here -

[Rails, Facebook API, Koala gem — get all profiles of users who 'Like' a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262163/rails-facebook-api-koala-gem-get-all-profiles-of-users-who-like-a-page)

But this is very old and does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: "The docs say acting as a page is much the same as acting as a user and the same commands should work." - where do the docs say that? also, what for exactly do you want to get the users who liked your page?

Comment: another question: "...can get access to their feeds..." you can only do that if users authorize your app with the user_posts permission. even then, you don´t get access to their feed, but only to their own posts.

Comment: Pages don’t have “friends”, and friends and likes are not the same thing to begin with. There is no way to get a list of all people who liked your page via API.

Comment: @luschn - Regards 1st question it says it here at the bottom of the page -

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page

Yes I am only after their posts not their entire feed! Will try to edit the question.

Comment: @04FS yes I am aware which is why it is weird it does not have anything about getting them specifically in the docs. It does seem possible as per the old Stack post but unsure of the updated commands.

Comment: That question you are referring to is over _n.i.n.e._ years old … There is no way with the current APIs, to get what you want. It’s not in the docs, because it does not exist.

Comment: @luschn in terms of what we want from this we want to get access to their posts looking for when they post about certain topics so we can use those posts in our app...

Comment: @04FS sure but this part of the FB API docs seems to show that you can still get it for any object in the graph api?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/likes

Comment: _“This reference describes the /likes edge that is common to multiple Graph API nodes.”_ - it would say “all” instead of “multiple” there, if that was what it meant. But it doesn’t. [`/{page-id}/likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/page/likes) gets you the objects liked _by_ that page. There is no way to get the user profiles that liked your page.

Comment: that github link is not official docs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/likes

> A User or Page can only query their own likes.

In other words, you can only get Pages that are liked by the Page in question - or Pages that are liked by the User, if authorized with the `user_likes` permission and with a User Token.

**There is no way to get Page Fans, and accessing the posts of a User is only possible by authorizing that User with the `user_posts` permission.**

Btw, `/me/friends` is for getting the friends of a User, and it would only return friends who authorized the App too.

Comment: OK thanks - I guess the only way then is if the users log into our app using Facebook and grant us the user_posts permission?

Comment: yeah, without authorization, you cannot get ANY data of a user, for privacy reasons.